# How to optimize MySQL database/query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, database-indexes

Hi I was hoping I could get some help on how to optimize my database so it doesn't take a year. I know that to speed it up I need to add indexes, but I'm not exactly sure on what I should be adding them on.

Heres the three tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `journeyPattern2` (
  `journeyPatternId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serviceId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `direction` enum('inbound','outbound') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`journeyPatternId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `journeyPatternTimingLink2` (
  `journeyPatternTimingLinkId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `journeyPatternId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `to` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `direction` enum('inbound','outbound') NOT NULL,
  `runTime` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`journeyPatternTimingLinkId`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `line` (
  `lineId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serviceId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lineName` tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lineId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service` (
  `serviceId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serviceCode` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `registeredOperatorRef` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `origin` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `destination` tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`serviceId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

The table journeyPattern2 contains about 33000 rows, journeyPatternTimingLink2 contains around 13 million, and line and service around 70000.

The query I'm trying to optimize is the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT lineName,line.serviceId  FROM `journeyPatternTimingLink2` 
INNER JOIN journeyPattern2
ON journeyPattern2.journeyPatternId=journeyPatternTimingLink2.journeyPatternId
INNER JOIN line
ON journeyPattern2.serviceId = line.serviceId
WHERE `from` = '13006785E'
```

I've never really worked with tables of this size before so I'm not sure if I'm joining correctly in the first place. I've also uploaded a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJW8f.png) of me running EXPLAIN on the query from phpmyadmin, but I'm not exactly sure how to interpret the results so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: First, is your query really slow or do you want to optimize in advance?

Comment: Yeah its very slow, 50 seconds to run what I posted above.

Comment: Your explain talks about 330141 rows in journeyPattern2, above you said 33000 rows, which is correct?

Comment: Yeah, I was just estimating the number of rows. I've followed the advice below and the same query is down from 50 seconds to 0.04 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add some indexes to these fields -

- journeyPatternTimingLink2.journeyPatternId
- journeyPattern2.serviceId
- line.serviceId
- journeyPatternTimingLink2.`from`

These are indexes used in JOIN-ON clauses and WHERE condition.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add some *foreign keys* or *indexes* on below mentioned columns:

1. Add reference on `jouurneyPatternId` column from `journeyPattern2` to `journeyPatternTimingLink2`
2. Add reference on `serviceId` column from `service` to `journeyPattern2`
3. Add reference on `serviceId` column from `service` to `line`

Add index on `from` column in `journeyPatternTimingLink2` table.

Comment: Adding foreign keys is not possible on tables using myisam engine.

Comment: Add indexes on that columns that also improve the performance

Answer (score 1):

The most important index should be on `journeyPatternTimingLink2.from`, because this is in your where clause and has two orders of magnitude more rows than all other tables combined.

You might also consider using InnoDB for all your tables. From [Optimization Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-overview.html):

> **Note**
>
> In MySQL 5.5 and higher, InnoDB is the default storage engine for new
>   tables. In practice, the advanced InnoDB performance features mean
>   that InnoDB tables often outperform the simpler MyISAM tables,
>   especially for a busy database.